# Retrieve single value from azure mobile services data table

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I am new to Windows Azure mobile services. I am trying to build an application for windows phone 8. I have created a table on azure.

```
 public class myTabble { public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "age")]
    public int age { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fname")]
    public string fname { get; set; }
  }
```

I can retrieve the full row by using

```
private MobileServiceCollection items;

private IMobileServiceTable<myTabble> todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<myTabble>();
items = await todoTable
        .Where(todoItem => todoItem.name == null)
        .ToCollectionAsync();

items = await todoTable.ToCollectionAsync();
```

But I dont Know how to retrieve a single data from the table. For example if I want to store the fname of a user whose name is "X" in a string variable. How can I retrieve only a single entity related with a particular user. Thank you.

Comment: I've been looking for a while, and I don't think you can get a single instance, only collections (which is absurd :/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .Select to property to get only a certain column:

```
var names = await todoTable
                  .Where(t => t.name == NameIWant)
                  .Select(t => t.fname)
                  .ToCollectionsAsync();
```

See: [HowTo: Select Specific Columns from the .NET Reference Guide](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#selecting)

(Also if you know the Id of the user already, you could use LookupAsync over the where clause)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. but i am not able to use a string value in place of "NameIWant". If i am using a string value I am getting error at .ToCollectionsAsync();

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I can see the first is not ideal as it still returns a list initially

```
IMobileServiceTableQuery<todoTable> query = todoTable.Where(t => t.fname == "[Your Name]");
            var res = await query.ToListAsync();
            var item = res.First();
            //fName is a string in your object MyTable just get it like this
            string fname = item.fname;
```

You could also write a SQL query in windows azure Mobile services, API to retrieve a single record then call it from your app like this

```
var result = App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<todoTable>("[Your MobileServices API name]",
                                                           HttpMethod.GET,
                                                           null);
```

Comment: i am not able to store it in a string variable like explained here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087755/specific-value-from-azure-mobile-services-table

Comment: There's no such a thing as `LoadAllAsync`. You need either `ToListAsync` or `ToEnumerableAsync`. @dellywheel, can you please edit your answer to fix your code?

Comment: @carlosfigueira opps my mistake thought my own extension method was in the MobileServices API. edited the answer