# Specific value from azure mobile services table

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I have a data table which looks like

```
id        name          age           emailId 

X         bill           20           bill@abc.com 
y         john           19           bob@abc.com
```

on client side application

```
    public class myTabble { public string Id { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
public string name { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "age")]
public int age { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
public string email { get; set; }
```

I am trying to store the name of the user having email id bob@abc.com by

```
var names = await todoTable
               .Where(t => t.email == "bob@abc.com")
               .Select(t => t.fname)
              .ToCollectionAsync();

                string myName = Convert.ToString(names);
```

but it is not working. How can I do this please help.

Comment: The first trap could be your where clause: Shouldn't it be `.Where(t => t.email == "bob@abc.com")`?

Comment: sorry actually it was t.email i typed here wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ToCollectionAsync` will give you a collection object (an ObservableCollection), one which you can use to bind the results with a UI control (such as a list view). If you want to programmatically get a value, you should use one of the other methods to retrieve data from the table, either `ToListAsync` or `ToCollectionAsync`:

```
var names = await todoTable
    .Where(t => t.email == "bob@abc.com")
    .Select(t => t.fname)
    .ToEnumerableAsync();
var myName = name.FirstOrDefault(); // name will be null if not found
```